# How do I prevent Sphinx from adding the "container" class when using the container directive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-sphinx

I am currently building out documentation using Sphinx.  I have created a custom theme that uses Bootstrap for aiding in responsive design of the site. There are some elements in the documentation that I want to wrap in a div which I can do with the Container directive. The problem I have is that the directive keeps adding a "container" class to the resulting div which has a specific meaning in Bootstrap.  Is there any way to suppress having this extra class added to the markup?  I can work around the issue by using the Raw directive, but as the documentation says, that is basically only there for extreme cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately created a new "div" directive which doesn't add any classes not specified.  While having classes added to rendered page elements is useful in some situations, I believe that should be something controlled by the author and not an arbitrary decision made by Sphinx or docutils.  My [div directive](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Docs/blob/master/common/ext/div.py) is available on GitHub.